# Make Nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I connected mySQL from PHP for use in Android Studio. I want to do JSON parsing with nested Array.

And I have another question. Can I create recyclerView in recyclerView in Android Studio using nested JSON?
The final goal is to create a nested recyclerView and show them.
Please advise me in any way.

my JSON result like this now

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "store_num": "1000001",
      "store_name": "store1",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu1",
        "menu_price": "2000"
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000001",
      "store_name": "name1",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu2",
        "menu_price": "500"
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000002",
      "store_name": "store2",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu3",
        "menu_price": "2000"
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000002",
      "store_name": "store2",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu4",
        "menu_price": "1000"
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000002",
      "store_name": "store2",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu5",
        "menu_price": "2000"
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000003",
      "store_name": "store3",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu6",
        "menu_price": "2000"
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000003",
      "store_name": "store3",
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": "menu7",
        "menu_price": "2500"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want grouping by store_num, store_name like this

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "store_num": "1000001",
      "store_name": "store1",
      "store_menu": [
        {
        "menu_name": "menu1",
        "menu_price": "2000"
        },
        {
        "menu_name": "menu2",
        "menu_price": "500"
      }
      ]
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000002",
      "store_name": "store2",
      "store_menu": [
        {
          "menu_name": "menu3",
          "menu_price": "2000"
        },
        {
          "menu_name": "menu4",
          "menu_price": "1000"
        },
        {
          "menu_name": "menu5",
          "menu_price": "2000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "store_num": "1000003",
      "store_name": "store3",
      "store_menu": [
        {
          "menu_name": "menu6",
          "menu_price": "2000"
        },
        {
          "menu_name": "menu7",
          "menu_price": "2500"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my PHP code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("IP","userName","PW","DBName");


if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");


$res = mysqli_query($con, 
    "select store.store_num, store.store_name, menu.menu_name, menu.menu_price
    from store, menu
    where store.store_num = menu.store_num");

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{

    array_push($result, 
        array(
            'store_num'=>$row[0], 
            'store_name'=>$row[1],
            'store_menu'=>
            array(
                'menu_name'=>$row[2], 
                'menu_price'=>$row[3]
            )
        )
    );

}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I maked json_obect() in mysql But It looks strange : too many unknown slash, print null value, incorrect order. But, this code is printed in the correct shape in phpmyadmin (except for incorrect order)

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "store_num": "{\"store_num\": 1000001, \"store_menu\": [{\"menu_name\": \"menu1\", \"menu_price\": 2000}, {\"menu_name\": \"menu2\", \"menu_price\": 500}], \"store_name\": \"store1\"}",
      "store_name": null,
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": null,
        "menu_price": null
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "{\"store_num\": 1000002, \"store_menu\": [{\"menu_name\": \"menu3\", \"menu_price\": 2000}, {\"menu_name\": \"menu4\", \"menu_price\": 1000}, {\"menu_name\": \"menu5\", \"menu_price\": 2000}], \"store_name\": \"store2\"}",
      "store_name": null,
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": null,
        "menu_price": null
      }
    },
    {
      "store_num": "{\"store_num\": 1000003, \"store_menu\": [{\"menu_name\": \"menu6\", \"menu_price\": 2000}, {\"menu_name\": \"menu7\", \"menu_price\": 2800}], \"store_name\": \"store3\"}",
      "store_name": null,
      "store_menu": {
        "menu_name": null,
        "menu_price": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code for the above results.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("IP","userName","PW","DBName");


if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");


$res = mysqli_query($con, 
    "select json_object('store_num', store.store_num, 'store_name', store_name, 'store_menu', json_arrayagg( json_object( 'menu_name', menu.menu_name, 'menu_price', menu.menu_price ))) from store inner join menu on menu.store_num = store.store_num GROUP BY store.store_num, store_name");

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{

    array_push($result, 
        array(
            'store_num'=>$row[0], 
            'store_name'=>$row[1],
            'store_menu'=>
            array(
                'menu_name'=>$row[2], 
                'menu_price'=>$row[3]
            )
        )
    );

}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! Can you provide the schema for both tables `store` and `menu`? Thanks!

Comment: In the meanwhile, I created the schema myself. Can you try to change the body of the `while` loop in your last example to `print_r($row)` and paste the content here? The query with `json_object()` returns the right structure but it isn't properly encoded in your example.